# MSBuild Issue for jenkins build step System account

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, nuget

I'm trying to build UWP project, project builds correctly if i run the script from command line myself. if i use the same script in jenkins it fails with this error,i searched a lot to find the solution and someone suggested to use `NUGET_PACKAGES=C:\NugetPackageCache` but that didn't help either.
I'm still getting the error below

> (ResolveNuGetPackageAssets target) -> 
>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\15.0\Microsoft.NuGet.targets(186,5):
>   error : The package Microsoft.CSharp with version 4.0.1 could not be
>   found in C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile.nuget\packages